# Using Jest with react-scripts (run via yarn), how do I get a full coverage report without having to pass watchAll flag?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I have a basic create-react-app setup called jest-playground-1 with a package.json file of

```
{
  "name": "jest-playground-1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^6.10.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "coverageReporters": [
      "html",
      "text"
    ]
  }
}
```

when I run `yarn test --coverage` (note the `--coverage` flag is passed through to Jest as per the docs), I am expecting to see All of the files in my brand new project.

Instead, I see no files, and the Jest runner looks like

```
No tests found related to files changed since last commit.
Press `a` to run all tests, or run Jest with `--watchAll`.
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

Interestingly, if I run it with `--watchAll`, I see the output I am expecting:

```
 PASS  src/App.test.js
  ✓ renders learn react link (49ms)

------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File              |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files         |     2.44 |        0 |     6.25 |     2.44 |                   |
 App.js           |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.js         |        0 |      100 |      100 |        0 |              7,12 |
 serviceWorker.js |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |... 25,132,133,134 |
------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.591s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press o to only run tests related to changed files.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

As you can see, when run with `--watchAll` flag I see the three files in the project App.js, index.js, and serviceWorker.js

How can I tell Jest to run these by default without having to pass the --watchAll flag?

Comment: I have no such file; this is on a brand new create-react-app with package dependancies added only with yarn (the ones you see in the package.json)

Comment: try to add "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
  ]

Comment: nope… I tried to added `collectCoverageFrom": [ "src/**/*.{js,jsx}" ]` but I got the same results… no files listed

Comment: yarn test --coverage --watchAll

Comment: so you're saying I should just always run it with the `--watchAll` flag?

Comment: yes, as mentioned. I don't know what the settings under the hood

Comment: @JasonFB what is your use case?

Comment: my use case is to run `yarn test` from the command line on my local development machine. I would like to see all of my files listed in my coverage report. As of as far as I can tell, it is necessary to pass `--watchAll` flag when running the test suite in addition to the `--coverage` flag. this seems counter-intuitive to me, and it is also not documented so I am wonder if there is something I missed or if this maybe be better documented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass --watch "your file extension"

```
"scripts": {
.
.
.
  "test": "react-scripts test --coverage --watch .test.js"
.
.
.
```